# uploading csv file to sqlite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, csv

I am trying to upload my csv data to my sqlite table, this is my code:

```
require 'csv'

CSV.open('history.csv', 'r') do |row|
  HistoryYear.create(:year => row[1], :first => row[2], :second => row[3], :third => row[4], :regular_season_champ => row[5])
end
```

I am receiving an error message, `NoMethodError: undefined method '[]' for #<CSV:0x3c1fe18>`.  I am a new to Rails and programming in general and cannot seem to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CSV.foreach(file...) instead

You can do something like:

```
require 'csv'

CSV.foreach('history.csv') do |row|
  HistoryYear.create(:year => row[1], :first => row[2], :second => row[3], :third => row[4], :regular_season_champ => row[5])
end
```

Check out http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html

Answer (score 0):

Also don't forget that arrays (the rows in this case) are 0 indexed i.e. the first element of the row is row[0].